# Elasticsearch: Versioning a document on revisions

Tags: elasticsearch

I currently have a document which gets revised regularly, I want to keep track of the document by keeping each old version of the document. So if document A has a summary and update date I want to, after every update, keep the previous version along with its update data.

The problem is that I'm not sure how I should do this efficiently:

```
...{
        Title: A
        Summary: {update_date:content, update_date:content, ...}
    }
```

The problem is that if I take the key as value then the automatic generated schema will take all dates as possible keys. Which is not something you want.

So my question is what's the most efficient way of tracking all revisions by date in ElasticSearch?

Comment: Have you found any solution for this? because I have the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

Just like everything related to building an index, it highly depends on what you want to do with the data.

Typically, keeping past revisions is done for auditing purposes, so it's an entirely different query flow. I would likely keep one index for the active documents, and a separate index (with possible date partitions) for the revisions.

Each update requires to update the live document and an insertion of a new document in the revision index.

It should also be noted that ElasticSearch has some [native support for versioning](http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/elasticsearch-versioning-support/), which might be suitable for you. I personally use ES as an index only and not a data store, so I tend to drop indices and rebuild often, which would cause history to be lost.

Comment: The problem with the native versioning support is that you can indeed have external versioning, but you'd keep in elasticsearch only the latest version, not all the revisions as mentioned in the question.